# MultiMarkdown in Notepad ++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, multimarkdown

What methods are available to use Notepad++ as a MultiMarkdown editor/viewer?  I have been unable to locate anything in Google, and was wondering what recommendations exist?

Just to be clear, by MultiMarkdown I mean [this](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/features/) *NOT* just markdown.

Comment: just to be clear: With MultiMarkdown you mean [this](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/features/)?

Comment: Just added your comment to my question.

Comment: A Markdown syntax highlighting module is available [at this web site](https://github.com/thomsmits/markdown_npp). To my knowledge, NPP++ does not have the capacity to render text for viewing (in any format), but can be configured to call a rendering program to view the file that you are working on.